# Labels al top de graficos

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Estoy realizando una grafica, usando [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), funciona, ahora necesito ubicar el label que muestra la información dentro de la barra del grafico o arriba de este usando [Chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) , uso la forma de la [documentación](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/bar.html), pero no me esta funcionando la configuración recomendada, de esta forma estoy construyendo el grafico:

```
new Chart("CostScrap_sf", {
                type: "bar",
                data: {
                    labels: records.map(function (e) { return e.fecha }),
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Sunroof',
                        backgroundColor: color,
                        data: records.map(function (e) { return e.total })
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    plugins: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Scrap Cost from ' + $datein.value + ' to ' + $dateout.value
                        },
                        datalabels: {
                            color: 'white',
                            display: function (context) {
                                return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] > 15;
                            },
                            font: {
                                weight: 'bold'
                            },
                            formatter: Math.round
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Se supondría que el atributo `datalabels` funcionaria para configurarlo, el resultado que espero es algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo a cuál label te refieres ni a donde lo quieres ubicar

Comment: Gracias @Yussef, agregue lo que tengo actualmente, espero ser mas claro

Comment: Lo que está en rojo es lo que quieres reubicar y en donde?

Comment: Lo que esta en el rectángulo amarillo quiero ubicarlo donde esta el rectángulo rojo

Comment: Me mataste, entendí menos. El mismo valor que está en el amarillo está en el rojo. O ese todo el tooltip que quieres posicionarlo por sobre el gráfico?

Comment: Edite la imagen para "ejemplificar", **el valor dentro del rectángulo rojo lo edite yo**

Comment: ahhh quieres poner el valor sobre el gráfico (yo pensaba que ese valor estaba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Utilizar el plugin [Datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/), debes:

1. agregarlo la librería despúes de la de chart.js
2. Registrarla con `Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);`

Demo:

```js
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
var ctx = document.getElementById("articulos").getContext('2d');
var ventas = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["RETEN DE EMBOLO", "RETEN DE EMPOLO"],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Artículos más vendidos',
      data: [4,8],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(0,166,149,255)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
        datalabels: { //esta es la configuración de pluggin datalabels
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'top',
            formatter: Math.round,
            font: {
                weight: 'bold'
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
<div style="width:600px;height:400px">
   <canvas id="articulos"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: como que algo extraño ocurre cuando pones el cursor en la barra...

Comment: Era la versión del chart.js ya la cambié y corregido

Comment: Efectivamente!, me hacia falta la linea `Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);` , la agregue y funciono como se esperaba.

Comment: @Yussef, acabo de darme cuenta de esto; tengo más gráficos en la misma pagina que el grafico que mencione en la pregunta, y cuando actualizo el grafico con el que me ayudaste, se dibuja (correctamente) pero lanza en la consola `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_listened')` y el resto de canvas quedan en blanco a pesar de que ya estaban dibujados seguí este [hilo](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/issues/309), pero creo que no lo han resuelto,  ¿has presentado un problema similar?

Comment: Acabo de probar con 2 gráficos y no tengo ese problemas. Cuando dices actualizar te refieres a que cambias los datos originales, y si es así, como lo estas haciendo?

Comment: @Yussef **Actualice la pregunta**, al terminar la carga de la pagina, algunos gráficos los cargo sin intervención del usuario, para el grafico con el que me ayudaste, lo dibujo a partir del `onchange` de 2 inputs y que manda a llamar la función `GraphCost()` que agregue a la pregunta, una vez que `GraphCost()` termina se arroja el error y los demás gráficos desaparecen.

Comment: Debes generar otra pregunta para este caso, porque 1) nadie la va a mirar porque ya tiene respuesta y 2) Estas cambiando el sentido de la pregunta. Reversa los cambios que has hecho para dejarla como antes