# ¿Cómo lograr que las etiquetas y el valor de cada ítem se vean encima de cada barra del gráfico utilizando la biblioteca chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Estoy utilizando la librería chart.js para graficar los datos de una tabla html. Estuve leyendo la documentación de dicha librería y no encuentro la función que busco: necesito que el número perteneciente a cada barra se vea sobre la misma todo el tiempo. A continuación dejo el código:

```js
/*Nuevo grafico*/
function graficar2(titulo_grafico, nombre_tabla, id_canvas, indice_eje_x, indice_eje_y) {

  const tabla = document.getElementById(nombre_tabla)

  let datos_eje_x = []

  let datos_eje_y = []

  let coloresDeFondoDeBarras = ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 51, 0, 0.2)'];

  let colorDeBordeDeBarras = ['rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'];

  let fondo = [];

  let borde = [];

  for (var i = 1, row; row = tabla.rows[i]; i++) {

    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {

      if (j === 0) {

        datos_eje_x.push(col.textContent)

      } else if (j === 1) {

        datos_eje_y.push(col.textContent)

        //Si el numero de la columna es negativo, se asigna color rojo a la barra, de lo contrario, se asigna color azul
        if (Math.sign(col.textContent) === -1 || Math.sign(col.textContent) === -0) {

          //Insertamos el color de fondo rojo.
          fondo.push(coloresDeFondoDeBarras[1])

          //Insertamos el color de borde rojo
          borde.push(colorDeBordeDeBarras[1])
        } else {

          //Insertamos el color de fondo rojo.
          fondo.push(coloresDeFondoDeBarras[0])

          //Insertamos el color de borde rojo
          borde.push(colorDeBordeDeBarras[0])

        } //fin else

      }

    } //Fin bucle for j

  } //Fin bucle for i


  const ctx = document.getElementById(id_canvas).getContext('2d');

  // Podemos tener varios conjuntos de datos. Comencemos con uno
  const datos = {
    label: titulo_grafico,
    // Pasar los datos igualmente desde PHP
    data: datos_eje_y, // <- Aquí estamos pasando el valor traído usando AJAX
    backgroundColor: fondo, // Color de fondo
    borderColor: borde, // Color del borde
    borderWidth: 1, // Ancho del borde


  };

  const nuevoGrafico = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar', // Tipo de gráfica
    data: {
      labels: datos_eje_x,
      datasets: [

        datos,
        // Aquí más datos...
      ]

    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        yAxes: [{
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }],
      },
      //inicio
      responsive: true,
      showTooltips: false,
      onAnimationComplete: function() {

        var ctx = nuevoGrafico;
        ctx.font = this.scale.font;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.scale.textColor
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";

        this.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
          dataset.bars.forEach(function(bar) {
            ctx.fillText(bar.value, bar.x, bar.y - 5);
          });
        })
      }
      //fin
    }
  })


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans+Narrow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos/estilos.css">

  <!-- Importar chart.js -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Importar funcion graficar del archivo javascript -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script_grafico.js"></script>

  <title>Prueba</title>

</head>

<body>

  <table id="tabla5">

    <thead>

      <tr>

        <th>PROVÍNCIA</th>

        <th>COMPAÑIA</th>

      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

      <tr>

        <td>BUENOS AIRES</td>
        <td>-2.84</td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td>CAPITAL FEDERAL</td>
        <td>1.44</td>

      </tr>

      <!--<tr>
    
                <td>CATAMARCA</td>
                <td>-0.59</td>
    
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
    
                <td>CORDOBA</td>
                <td>-1.82</td>
    
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
    
                <td>CORRIENTES</td>
                <td>0.68</td>
    
                </tr>-->


    </tbody>

  </table>

  <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tabla5', 'compañia')">Descargar</button>

  <div class="row row-cols-12">

    <canvas id="grafica2">
    
        <script>graficar2('Variación Interanual','tabla5','grafica2',1,2)</script>
        </canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/procesos.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

**Resultado actual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El resultado que busco**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aquí un ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/577084/301324. Aquí la solución para que el label no salga del gráfico cuando este cubre todo el eje Y https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/586695/301324

Comment: Ojo con la versión que estas usando que es más vieja que matulsalén